# How to Store Array Data Using Laravel foreach with ORM

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, laravel-5

create_team_social_icons_table.php

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('order_id');
        $table->integer('team_id');
        $table->integer('social_class');
        $table->string('link');
```

Hello,
I have two different array from create form social_class[] and link[]. Trying to record values from a form using the form at one time.

```
<select name="social_class[]">
<select name="social_class[]">
<select name="social_class[]">
<select name="link[]">
<select name="link[]">
<select name="link[]">
```

I received an error message:

preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array.

```
        $social_class = Input::get('social_class');
        $link = Input::get('link');
        foreach ($social_class as $socialClass) {
            $tsi = new TeamSocialIcon();
            $tsi->order_id = 0;
            $tsi->team_id = $insertedId;
            $tsi->social_class = $socialClass;
            $tsi->link = $link;
            $tsi->save();
        }
```

Comment: When are you using `$sc`? it seems to me you are trying to save the `$social_class` array, not the array element. Try, changing: `$tsi->social_class = $social_class;` to `$tsi->social_class = $sc;`

Comment: Hello I use `$tsi->social_class = $socialClass;`   and updated some variable but `tsi->link` or `$link` still not catch value. and preg_replace error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replied to myself for my solution

```
$social_class = $request->social_class;
$link = $request->link;

        for($i = 0; $i < count($social_class); $i++) {
            $tsi = new TeamSocialIcon();
            $tsi->order_id = 0;
            $tsi->team_id = $insertedId;
            $tsi->social_class = $social_class[$i];
            $tsi->link = $link[$i];
            $tsi->save();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the array into string using explode method. You should also change the column data type to string or varchar for the data to be successfully saved. While retrieving the data you can convert the string back into array using implode method.